# hash content and then convert to hex result

Tags: java, hash, encoding, character-encoding, digest

I have a string:

```
String message = "{\"name\":\"三菱グループ\"}\n"
```

operations that I want to perform on this message:

1. Hash the message using SHA-256 algo
2. convert the hash from step 1 to lowercase hex string

my app produced

```
25335a59763ad40ae13d1d4a011efcdc2aa2c4885295aebeb393bc96bb927f66
```

anybody got different result?
I;ve been scratching my head because a remote server insisted that the correct result is

```
20de051e351ebc53c83902a72ac916e5a46228fc3e5ec070bf441612e20164d9
```

I'm under the assumption that so long the message stays the same, the result of these operations will always be the same, no matter how many times you perform these 2 chained operations on the same message. Let me know if this is not the case.

I'm adding another test message (newline character removed):
for

```
String message = "{\"name\":\"三菱グループ\"}";
```

my code produced

```
7902fb68f1f90f700788613e7f667968beb4abd724abb545e00e01d65e74a772
```

and the remote server produced

```
d3df5e50703eb5ff2fd17210af93b6b2ef1e5640c89787405352998d955a4e63
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried passing your strings to an [online SHA256 calculator](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator), and got the same output as your app has produced, both with and without line break.

> the calc result will always be the same between me and the server so long the message doesnt contain any non-latin characters.

Since SHA256 algorithm operates on a sequence of bytes, there is one more step your program takes: it converts the `String` to an array of bytes, i.e. something like this:

```
text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

If the server is using an encoding different from UTF-8 or whatever you are using, the result of this conversion is going to be different.

When you send a string with only Latin characters, all characters would be encoded as a single byte, and there would be no place for a difference.

Comment: this is not an online tool, but this message is transmitted as a string.

Comment: added another example, this time without newline character

Comment: @musicsquad I pasted `{"name":"三菱グループ"}` into the online calculator, and got your result back, i.e. `7902fb68f1f90f700788613e7f667968beb4abd724abb545e00e01d65e74a772`. It is clear that the server is not computing the SHA on the same sequence of bytes as does your program.

Comment: same sequence of bytes? are you talking about endianness? the calc result will always be the same between me and the server so long the message doesnt contain any non-latin characters. if the message contains even just one umlaut or non latin character, it will be different.

Comment: how many encoding are there? please say there are only 4 or five of 'em, so I can try one by one to see which one is used by the server

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/encodings.html), there are three JIS encodings (Shift JIS, EUC, ISO-2022-JP) and three Unicode encodings (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32) in widespread use. You can rule out UTF-16 and UTF-32 because Latin text produces the same hash.

Comment: wait, that page is for japanese encodings, does that mean Russian, Korean, Arabic, Aramaic, etc will have their own encodings?

Comment: @musicsquad Yes, only UTF-8 can handle them all. The best way to find out what your server does is to take a look at its source code. If that is not an option, try to see what technology stack it is using (Java? .NET? Something else?)

Answer (score 0):

This very strongly depends on how you are passing this to a remote server. For example, some servers will not decode Asian characters correctly within a GET request. Other servers will trim inputted data. Without more information on how you are passing this to the remote server, it might be hard to find out the answer.

Comment: I see. but did you get the same result as mine? both the example with and without newline character? thanks

Comment: I did (with the newline, obviously without the newline the hash is different, but still not the same as you get). I do believe it might be a problem with decoding Asian characters, but without seeing the communication code I can't tell more.

Comment: not the same for the one without newline? what did you get for the one without newline?

Comment: 7902fb68f1f90f700788613e7f667968beb4abd724abb545e00e01d65e74a772

Answer (score 0):

```
String message = "{\"name\":\"三菱グループ\"}";
String sha256hex = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(message);
System.out.println("hash: " + sha256hex);
```

Result:
hash: 7902fb68f1f90f700788613e7f667968beb4abd724abb545e00e01d65e74a772

Do you know if the remote server using bash script by any chance in that case you need to add an other "\" to your message. So it become "{\\"name\\":\\"三菱グループ\\"}";

Comment: the message is sent without any backslashes. the backslashes are only in java code (for string literal escaping).

Comment: In that case the remote server is not calculating it right. On all online tools the result same as yours. i.e. http://www.freeformatter.com/sha256-generator.html#ad-output.